# Time complextity and efficiency

Tags: c, time, complexity-theory

I have written two programs to find the number of divisors of a number.

The first function has less code than the second one but for a number like 500 000, it make 250 001 iterations.

However the second function which has more code make 800 iterations.

Which function is more efficient than the other regarding time complexity ?

```
int divisors(int n) 
{
  int i, count = 1;
  
  for (i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++) 
  {
    if (n % i == 0)
      count ++;
  } 
  
  return count;
}


 int divisors(int nbr)
 {
    int div_1=1;
    int div_2=0;
    int n_div=0;
    
    
    do {
        
        if (nbr % div_1 == 0)
        {
            div_2 = nbr / div_1;
            if(div_1==div_2)
            {
                n_div+=1;
            }
            else
            { n_div+= 2; }
        }
        div_1 ++;

    }while(div_1<div_2);

    return n_div;
}
```

Comment: How precisely do _you_ define efficiency? What do you think about the question? This is a typical homework question, so indicating that you made an effort is important.

Comment: You could make the first one do fewer iterations using `i * i <= n` as the loop guard, since you can't have a divisor greater than the square root. Then it would only take ~700 iterations for your example.

Comment: You can't speak of efficiency without a specific system in mind. For example division is very performance-heavy on many ISA, whereas high end computers can execute sequential loops very fast unless there are branches in the loop body. Etc etc.

Comment: @AndyTurner it can. If `n` is even then `n/2 ` is a divisor. I think the idea of the second one is to count the 'other' divisor.

Comment: If `n/2` is a divisior you have already found it when you discovered 2 as a divisor. No need to loop beyond `i*i<=n`.

Comment: @Yunnosch that's the idea of the second code. The first is what it is.

Comment: I admit that I did not study/get the details of second code. Bit of a reflex on the `i<=n/2` vs `i*i<=n` check for sieve implementations, which are done at finding the first divisor.... I think the explanation is still helpful. MrFeli45, let me know if my comments confuse more than help. I will delete them then.

Comment: @Yunnosch effectively, the second code goes up to the square root. If the two roots are the same, it adds 1 to the count of divisors, otherwise 2. I think it would be more efficient to check outside the loop, whether the exact square root was reached (is a divisor). It's not very clean code to achieve what you suggested as an improvement to the first example.

Comment: @AndyTurner `i * i <= n` as a loop guard risks `int` overflow when `n` is near `INT_MAX`.  `i <= n/i` works well for all `n` and optimizes well considering the nearby `n % i`.

Comment: Complexity measurements usually refer to the rate of increase (and the shape of the curve) as N increases.  It has nothing to do with the absolute time for one particular value of N.  It's quite common for sophisticated algorithms — that have good performance (don't increase as much) for large N — to have terrible performance for small N.  It's also common for sophisticated algorithms to have more code.  "Big O" notation explicitly involves discarding any linear scaling.  So O(N) is better than O(N²), even if the O(N) algorithm is really O(100 × N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is [O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) with its `for (i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++)`.

The second is O(sqrt(n)) with its `div_2 = nbr / div_1;` and `}while(div_1<div_2);` - a lower time complexity.

With large enough `n`, the 2nd is more time efficient.

---

Note: Both loops use a `a % b` - a somewhat expensive operation.  The second uses a `a / b` -  another somewhat expensive operation.  A good compile will see these two nearby operations and perform them both for the about the cost of one.

---

Perhaps a 3rd alterative?  (Also O(sqrt(n)) )
This uses `div()` to compute the quotient and remainder in one operation for weak compilers that do not fold a common `/, %` together.  It moves the `div_1==div_2` to outside the loop as it never true more than once.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// Untested illustrative code.
int divisors3(int nbr) {
  int count = 0;
  int divisor = 1;
  div_t qr = { .quot = n };
  // Add 2 to the count for the distinct divisor and quotient.
  while (divisor < qr.quot) {
    if (qr.rem == 0) {
      count += 2;
    }
    divisor++;
    qr = div(nbr, divisor);
  }
  // Add 1 to the count for the common divisor and quotient.
  if (divisor == qr.quot) {
    if (qr.rem == 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count; 
}
```

---

More efferent code could take advantage of `divisor` being a multiple factor of `nbr`.